# Trouble uploading file in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following image upload code and controller. The hidden ID is POSTing successfully, but the image remains null.

The form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
<input type="hidden" name="merchandiseId" id="id" value="@ViewBag.Id"/>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />
<input type="submit" />
}
```

The controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddImage(int merchandiseId, HttpPostedFileBase image)
```

Debugging and stepping in verifies that image is null while merchandiseId has the correct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in your form. otherwise no file will be uploaded.

An example

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadAction", "MyController", new { Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
      <input type="file" name="myFile">
      <button type="submit>Upload</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }`to your form